# How to use nuget packages during build?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I want to use some tools during build that are acquired with nuget. Here is relevant part of `csproj` file:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(TargetPath)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="myAssemblyInfo"/>
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <Exec Command="nuget pack MyApp.nuspec -Version %(myAssemblyInfo.Version) -Properties Configuration=Release -OutputDirectory bin\Release -BasePath bin\Release" />
    <Exec Command="squirrel --no-msi --releasify bin\Release\MyApp.%(myAssemblyInfo.Version).nupkg" />
</Target>
```

Namely I want to use `Squirrel` and `NuGet` itself (contained in `NuGet.CommandLine` package) to build an installer. Executables are located in `packages\<package name>\tools\*.exe`. The lines used in `Exec` command work in Package Manager Console but Visual Studio can't find the executables during build (error 9009). It there a way to include package tools in current path during build to make them available?

Comment: Is this a Windows Store app, or a standard WPF/Winforms/Console app?  That does make a difference.

Comment: Have you tried a nuget package restore before building? https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore

Comment: Visual Studio does this automatically, but with MSBuild it's an extra step.

Comment: I'm building from Visual Studio. It already has all packages at latest version and VS has automatic restore turned on. Sometimes when I open Package Manager Console (without typing anything) it somehow loads tool paths and I can build successfully but sometimes it doesn't work.

Comment: I think `squirrell` is a powershell script, which means you need to invoke using `PowerShell -Command {squirrel --no-msi --releasify ....}`

Comment: it's an exe file and it works correctly sometimes when visual studio correctly loads packages